# Save 2D plot from MATLAB GUI in PNG format

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I am displaying some data into 2D format using MATLAB GUI axes. I want to get handle of this plot and save it to PNG image.

```
saveas(handle.axis1,'file.png')
```

Above code is saving entire GUI as PNG image and not just plot. How to just save a plot?

Comment: You probably need to create a new figure, as indicated in the accepted answer [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86693-save-axes-plot-as-fig-in-a-gui). You may want to create it as invisible (`Fig2 = figure('visible','off');`) so the user won't notice the trick

Comment: One more useful thing: [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). It can helps!

Answer (score 1):

when your figure is open:

```
print('myFigure','-dpng')
```